# Can I Pass the Text of a Link Through as a Variable?

Tags: javascript, variables

I have a simple html link.

```
<a onmouseover="myfunction(this.SOMETHING??);">The String I Want</a>
```

Is there any way to pass the text "The String I Want" as a variable into myfunction()? I was thinking I might be able to use the "this" keyword, so I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword), but it didn't really address this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.textContentText:

```
<a onmouseover="myfunction(this.textContent);">The String I Want</a>
```

But it works in everything except IE.

innerText only works with IE:

```
<a onmouseover="myfunction(this.innerText);">The String I Want</a>
```

As suggested by others, try this:

```
<a onmouseover="myfunction(this.innerText || this.textContent || '');">The String I Want</a>
```

This will use whichever one works, but in the event that innerText is empty and textContent is unsupported it will still pass an empty string instead of undefined.

Comment: `innerText` is unavailable in (at least) Firefox; `textContent`, however, works.

Comment: Something like `<a onmouseover="myfunction(this.innerText == undefined ? this.textContent : this.innerText);">The String I Want</a>` should be more appropriate.

Comment: @Jack - Yes totally. Old practices die hard. :-)

Comment: @Jack: Except that that will make the argument be `undefined` when `innerText` is empty and `textContent` is unsupported. `this.innerText || this.textContent || ""` would work, though.